# SharePoint 2013 AD FBA 2010 Compatibility

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication

I have a SharePoint 2013 server set up to use FBA through active directory. I've set up the claims providers following Microsoft guidelines from [TechNet Blog](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806890.aspx#proc3)

On a site collection using SharePoint 2013 experience, the people picker works correctly. AD accounts show up under the `Active Directory` category, and Forms Authentication accounts show up under `forms auth`.

[image: 2k13 Mode]

However, on sites running Sharepoint 2010 compatibility, both accounts will show up under `"organizations"`.

[image: 2K10 Mode]

I am guessing that the configuration is a little different for 2010 compatibility, however, I have been unsuccessful in my search for any documentation, any ideas?

Comment: This is a major issue because the FBA Management pack isnt working on the 2010 compatibility site, among other issues.

Comment: upon continued testing, this actually occurs whenever there is any site collection made on the web application, 2010 or 2013

Comment: Hi, @Matt Bear, old question, but web have exactly the same issue... Did you resolve it?

Comment: Yeah, I upgraded all the sites to 2013 experience... So no, not really a solution.